# Oracle 10g express home page is not coming up

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xe

I installed Oracle 10g express. Installation went well, But the home page is not coming up.
I can connect using sqlplus but not with Sql Developer. 
I checked tnsnames.ora and listener.ora everything looks fine.
Listener is also started. I can always reinstall and see. But I thought better inquire the cause.

Regarding the home page. This is the address that comes up in browser. Localhost:8080
http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex
I did a netstat to see whether there is any port conflict for 8080, but that port is not in use.

Have anybody faced this issue?

Comment: Here is a great tutorial, please check your installation steps against that: [https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301639](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301639)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It is practically a FAQ on the XE Oracle forum.
Firstly, can you connect to Oracle using

```
sqlplus user/pass
```

If so, Oracle is up an running (which appears to be your situation, but may not be for a future reader with a similar problem). If not, you can try

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
startup
```

Once Oracle is up, check that the listener can see the Oracle instance by
    sqlplus user/pass@xe
If not, then either the listener is not up, or the 'listener does not know of the service'. Make sure the listener is started (lsnrctl, then start). Make sure the database is registered with the listener

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
alter system register;
```

Now you should be able to connect  using the '@xe' syntax. Worthwhile verifying the embedded PL/SQL gateway is set up to use the 8080 port

```
select dbms_xdb.GETHTTPPORT from dual;
```

On Windows you can use netstat -ab to see if tnslsnr.exe is listening on the port.

Then I'd suggest looking at browser settings (specifically any proxy settings that might be forwarding your request to a machine that has no idea what to do with it) and firewalls (which could well be set to ignore or hide any access to the port).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried this and it sorted out my problem...
1. goto start->run
2.type services.msc and hit enter
3.In the applet that opened, scroll down(in right pane) to figure out the option of "OracleServiceXE" and right click on it.    4. In general tab do->>> startup type "Automatic" and click the "start button".
5. Repeat step 4. for the option "OracleXETNSListener".
 close the window.

now, i hope, the problem should be solved....

Answer (score 2):

Check your windows firewall,If it is on it blocks the opening of the homepage.Either you shut down the windows firewall or allow these following ports :
1521: Oracle database listener

2030: Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server

8080: HTTP port for Oracle XML DB and the Oracle Database XE graphical user interface

See software requirements in the below URL:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25143/toc.htm#BABEBCDB

It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this ( I'm assuming Windows system )

using

```
netstat
```

without anyother parameter would tell you if port 8080 is already open.

Also you can try this:

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

If the server answers ( the screen goes blank [or black] ) then the server is up and running.

Try using your hostname instead of localhost.

See if you're using a proxy and not skipping the local addresses.

Also you can see what's the executable that starts the home page and see if it could start successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response guys. 
I finally figured out how to solve the issue, but not really the root cause.

Problem 1 - Can not login to oracle admin console.
It was the problem with not adding 127.0.0.1 in the IE intranet sites.
Go to  tools>internet options>security>local intranet sites>advanced>
add http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex in the list.

It works fine after this.
But if I go back to the same place again and see the sites,  I cant find the url I added sometimes back... Dont know why that is happening. May be some company security is messing up. 
Anyways the admin console is now coming up.

Problem 2 -  Cannot connect using SQL Developer.
After I did the fix for problem 1, this is also magically working. 
I still don't know how security settings in IE affects SQL Developer?
Any comments on this?

Comment: There's a few different ways of connecting with SQL developer. I think it is like TNS or advanced. One of them gives the option of entering the server (127.0.0.1), port (1521) and service (XE).

Answer (score 0):

hey guys one important fact if u r using IE7 (explorer7) then u wd face certain problem in using 10g, such as not displaying home page.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8 simply click on `Get Started With OracleXE...`. When internet explorer opens up, select the `View on the desktop` option in the `Page View` icon (icon with a wrench).

You should now be able to view your page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I was able to connect to SQLPLUS using terminal but on access in browser as it was showing error as you have described. So, I went back to terminal and mounted my database using

> startup

and it resolved my problem. This might be the case.