# Oracle 10g express home page is not coming up

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

My Oracle 10g Express Edition , I can login in the SQL plus but I cannot login into oracle via SQL developer and cannot view the Home page at link http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex. This was working fine until yesterday.

I have checked via (WINDOWS)netstat -ab and no other app is using the 8080 port.

The only thing I did today was I changed my SQL server 2005 Developer edition from Windows authentication to Mixed Mode authentication.

Can anyone let me know how to get the Oracle Web page and the SQL Developer to work.

I will gratly appreciate that.

Thanks!

Adnan A.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531969/oracle-10g-express-home-page-is-not-coming-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK! I figured it out

All this time, I thought My listener was running but when i used the command

'lsnrctl status'

I noticed that lisnter was not running and was failing becasue my host name was correct.

I remember when I activated the Mixed Mode config for SQL Server 2005 , i had to give my SQL server a host name and which was different than generic WIndows XP hostname.

So i edited my TNSNAMES.ORA and LISTENER.ORA file by doind a search on windows for them and then fixed the hostnames.

Restarteds the Oracle XE services and now the WEB Page works and so does the SQL DeVELOPER.

SO I thought I should share with you the remedy.

Thanks for everyones help and efforts. YOu were all great.

Comment: thanks I had the same problem and mine is now resolved too thans to your post  :-)

Comment: I had a linux install and these two files were the culprits for me too. We had imaged another machine and it was still referencing the old machine name. I also had to update the /etc/hosts file and that seemed to fix everything.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your Oracle services?  If it still doesn't work then check the event viewer for any meaningful Oracle events.

And check that you didn't switch on a software firewall (Windows firewall or your AV program may have a firewall)

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is a recent issue, but I did find to my horror that an overly long workstation name when used with XE will cause the home page to not load.  I changed the name from (do not laugh!) GenericXPWorkstation  to VMORACLE and made sure Listener.ora and tnsnames.ora showed those values for host, as well as adding the entry 
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

to SQLNET.ORA and I now see the stupid XE admin homepage.

I did NOT screw with the Windows HOSTS file.