# Fiddler Echo Service blocking oracle homepage in browser

Tags: oracle, proxy

I have installed Oracle 10g and I can access it from cmd, but when I try to open it in the browser using localhost:8080, the following page is displayed.

```
Fiddler Echo Service


GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.703466998.1434348783


To configure Fiddler as a reverse proxy instead of seeing this page, see Reverse Proxy Setup
You can download the FiddlerRoot certificate
```

I have used the port 8080 initially. After this, when I changed the HTTP port to 4442, the connection is getting rejected, so I have once again changed the port to 8080.

I tried disabling Fiddler Proxy in Firewall and I have even disabled the firewall momentarily, but the issue remained persistent. I tried everything mentioned in "[Oracle 10g express home page is not coming up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531969/oracle-10g-express-home-page-is-not-coming-up)", without success.

What is the problem with this Fiddler and what do I have to do?