# Fiddler Echo Service error while accessing localhost in my chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat

I want to run apache-tomcat-6.0.44 server on my laptop. I have configured Classpath, Path and CATALINA_HOME variables. I am able to run the server from command prompt (using "startup" command). But the problem is, when I am typing "http://localhost:8080" in the url bar of my chrome browser and clicking enter, I am gettig error as:

> **Fiddler Echo Service**
>
> GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8080 Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
>   Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101
>   Safari/537.36 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch Accept-Language:
>   en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6 Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1441246844.1443724804 To
>   configure Fiddler as a reverse proxy instead of seeing this page, see
>   Reverse Proxy Setup You can download the FiddlerRoot certificate**

I have gone through some of the solutions, which are:

1) [Fiddler Echo Service blocking oracle homepage in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843327/fiddler-echo-service-blocking-oracle-homepage-in-browser)

2) [Fiddler not capturing traffic from browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644601/fiddler-not-capturing-traffic-from-browsers)

But I am still not able to fix the issue. Could anyone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Along with using proxy server, Check if your Lan setting is set to detect Automatically.

Go to below section of chrome 
"settings>Advanced settings>Network>Change Proxy settings" You shall get a wizard.
In there click "Lan Settings" and select the checkbox for "Automatically detect settings"

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is mismatch of crtificate installed.

server name used in Apache (httpd.conf) must be the same as the server name in apache (httpd-ssl.conf) e.g. in Apache (httpd.conf)ServerName localhost:8080 then in apache (httpd-ssl.conf) should be like this ServerName www.example.com:8080