# 11g XE GUI From Remote

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I installed Oracle 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit to a CENTOS 7 machine and opened up SSH so I can configure the machine from my windows laptop via putty. 11g installed successfully, but I can't seem to access 11g XE GUI from the web browser (http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex). I'm following [this](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_oracle_11g_xe_on) guide and haven't ran into any problems until this.

```
[root@localhost /]# sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Oct 27 22:21:58 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys/**** as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now when I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex in Chrome, I'm hit with:
This site can’t be reached

> 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. Try: Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I tried disabling my firewall on both my Linux machine and my windows machine, but it didn't have any effect. Any ideas on why I can't access it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below thread.

[Oracle 10g express home page is not coming up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531969/oracle-10g-express-home-page-is-not-coming-up)

In another case, adding 127.0.0.1 into the hosts file for windows resolved my issue.

Comment: select dbms_xdb.GETHTTPPORT from dual gives me  >>>> GETHTTPPORT
-----------
       8080
I also added  127.0.0.1       localhost to my hosts file. Didn't seem to effect anything

Comment: Are you able to telnet with 127.0.0.1 and 8080?

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused